# Printing out the lesson list in a course on custom template (course page for visitors) learndash get_course_lessons()

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I have used the shortcode to print out the course content or the list of lessons in a course but it doesnt work

I have tried using the below method

get_course_lessons();

when I add get_course_lessons(); , it says that 'get_course_lessons' is undefined, and the get course lessons is a public class in the following file wp-content/plugins/sfwd-lms/includes/classes/class-ldlms-factory-post.php

Is the above path is the right way if so how can i get it working or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use **learndash_get_course_lessons_list()**

```
learndash_get_course_lessons_list( int|WP_Post|null $course = null,  int|null $user_id = null,  array $lessons_args = array() )
```

Pass the course ID to $course and it will return all the lessons from that specefic course.