# How make the query correct for displaying all lessons assigned with course? (LearnDash plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

I ran into a little problem while working with LearnDach plugin. For my client, it is important that the user profile displays not a list of courses, but a list of lessons. For example, I bought courses: The Art of Makeup which consists of six lessons. If I just use the shortcode, I will display only the name of the enrolled course by clicking on which the user will be taken to the course page and from this page can go to the lesson. But I need to display in the profile something like this:

**Course Title**

- Lesson one link
- Lesson two link
- Lesson three link
- etc.

As you can see this is the course name and lessons associated with it.

This simple code:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$courses = learndash_user_get_enrolled_courses( $user_id, array(), true );
```

helps me find out the ID of the course the client is enrolled in. But how to get the lessons out of this course, I don’t understand. I've tried various loops but it doesn't work. Could someone help me to achieve the result?

I tried to use the following query format:

```
     $user_id = get_current_user_id();
     $courses = learndash_user_get_enrolled_courses( $user_id, array(), true );

     $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'sfwd-lessons',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post__in'      =>  $courses

      );

     $enrolled = new WP_Query( $args );

    while( $enrolled->have_posts() ) : $enrolled->the_post();
         the_title();
    endwhile;
```

As a result, nothing is output. And if I replace *'post_type' => 'sfwd-lessons'*, на *'post_type' => 'sfwd-courses'*, It will appear only the course for which the user is subscribed, but not the list of lessons that are published in this course. Could you please help me write the request correctly?

Comment: I think I've found the solution. The answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830130/printing-out-the-lesson-list-in-a-course-on-custom-template-course-page-for-vis help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very happy and in a hurry to share the solution. Perhaps it will be useful to someone. As I wrote in a comment to my question. The answer from this [Printing out the lesson list in a course on custom template (course page for visitors) learndash get_course_lessons()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64830130/printing-out-the-lesson-list-in-a-course-on-custom-template-course-page-for-vis) thread prompted me to a solution. And here is my code:

```
 <?php
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $courses = learndash_user_get_enrolled_courses( $user_id, 
    array(), true );
    $lessons = learndash_get_course_lessons_list( $courses[0],  $user_id,  
    array(), true );
 ?>

 <?php foreach ($lessons as $lesson):
     $postImage = get_the_post_thumbnail($lesson['post']->ID);
     $postTitle = $lesson['post']->post_title;
     $postLink = get_post_permalink($lesson['post']->ID);
 ?>

   <div> <?php echo $postTitle; ?> </div>

 <?php endforeach; ?>
```